# Java generics with inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have this structure of classes :

```
public class NFAddress

public class NFAddresses<T extends NFAddress> extends ArrayList<NFAddress>

public class NFMutableAddress extends NFAddress

public class NFMutableAddresses<T extends NFMutableAddress> extends NFAddresses<NFMutableAddress>
```

When I try to access objects in NFMutableAddresses

for (NFMutableAddress nucleusAddress : this)
        {
           object are defined as NFAddress and not NFMutableAddress 
        }

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: there is almost never a reason to extend ArrayList

Comment: I need to add a save method for dirty and new objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these class definitions instead:

```
public class NFAdressess<T extends NFAddress> extends ArrayList<T>
public class NFMutableAddresses<T extends NFMutableAddress> extends NFAddresses<T>
```

What is changed in comparison to your classes is that the generic parameter `T` is forwarded to the class being extended. This parameter `T` can be anything that (in the first case) extends the `NFAddress` (so it can be `NFMutableAddress` or anything else that extends any of those two).

Comment: When using this.add() I can  actually only pass T beaucause it extends ArrayList<T>. See code there http://pastebin.com/THEfzACV

Comment: Actually I've found how to do it : `this.add((T) new NFAddress());`